# Add UL of Markers Underneath Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to add a list of the place markers within my radius underneath my map. To do so is the new function calling the callback or createMarker function above?

My logic is to populate the list using the function that places the markers on my map.

Here is current code with the beginning of my list function commented out:

```
  var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;
var webster = new google.maps.LatLng(43.200371, -77.498245);

function initialize() {  
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
codeAddress();
var request = {
    location: webster,
    radius: 50000,
    types: ['store']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function codeAddress() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
  var address = '2450 Empire Blvd, Webster, NY 14580 US';   
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

function createUL(){
    var items = document.getElementById("results");

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerHTML = results[i];
        items.appendChild(item);
    }

}

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[jsfiddle.net/michaelkurz_/jgm72khd/33/](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelkurz_/jgm72khd/33/)

Comment: I don't see any attempt to create the information under the map.  For that matter, I don't see a map in your fiddle.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you are having, whatever it is.  I suspect you are trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_place-search_airport.html), but with the "sidebar" underneath.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why the map didn't load in fiddle. I edited the link. Hopefully it's working now. 

I am attempting to do something like the link provided. Question is do I call the createMarker or callback function to populate my list. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What list?  There is no attempt at a list in either your posted code or the linked fiddle (I do see a map now).  My example does it in the createMarker function, but you could do it in the callback function.

Comment: Apologies, must have been in the wrong fork. Code updated to show attempted and failed list generation.

Comment: Where do you call your `createUL` function?  Where does `results` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. call the createUL function.
2. pass the results from the places query into it.
3. save references to the markers (I did it in a `gmarkers` array)
4. link the name in the UL to the marker

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jgm72khd/34/)

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;
var webster = new google.maps.LatLng(43.200371, -77.498245);
var gmarkers = [];

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  codeAddress();
  var request = {
    location: webster,
    radius: 50000,
    types: ['store']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function codeAddress() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = '2450 Empire Blvd, Webster, NY 14580 US';
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
    createUL(results);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });



  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}

function createUL(results) {
  var items = document.getElementById("results");

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[" + i + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].name + "</a><br>";
    items.appendChild(item);
  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```